# Объект события в angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Как определить текущий элемент события, например нужно скрыть блок по которому кликнули. При этом список получаю динамично

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.name}}
    <p ng-click="hide(user.id)">Скрой меня</p>   
   </li>

</ul>


$scope.hide = function(id){ ..//код для скрытия блока по которому был клик  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно передать в функцию переменную `$event`:

```
<p ng-click="hide($event)">Скрой меня</p>
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то это будет обычный MouseEvent с его свойствами `target` и `currentTarget`. Но я бы сделал проще, если нужно только скрыть блок:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-hide="user.isHidden">
        {{user.name}}
        <p ng-click="user.isHidden = true">Скрой меня</p>   
    </li>
</ul>
```